# Capturing avrdude command in IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, command-line

With verbose upload selected the IDE provides the executed avrdude command at the top of the log.

I am interested in copy pasting that avrdude command. However at the end of the upload the command is not available anymore. The IDE only shows some last lines of the log and discard the top part.

Is that log saved anywhere? (I am on ubuntu). Any ideas how I can get that command?

Comment: If you run the IDE from a terminal you should get the output to STDOUT in your terminal to do with what you want.

Comment: That's the solution. Thanks a lot. I am using `arduino | tee cmd.txt` to capture it.

Comment: Disconnect the arduino from your PC before pressing upload. That way you get less output and it won't overwrite the top lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the IDE from a terminal you should get the output to STDOUT in your terminal to do with what you want.