# How to capture the compilaton output to a text file in Windows?

Tags: arduino-ide, compilation-errors, windows

I am trying to capture the verbose output of the compilation to get it into a text file. I am using the IDE 1.8.12 running on Windows 10. I have tried looking for a right mouse button context menu, CTRL-C doesn't work, and finally in desperation, the CMD.exe trick of hitting the Enter key after selecting text.

I also went to the build folder in appdata/local/temp/arduino_build_nnnnn but there's nothing like that there.

There is a topic already about this but it refers to the Linux IDE which can be launched from the command line. It turns out that it's somewhat the same on Windows.

Comment: in console window Ctrl+A to select all and Ctrl+C to copy should work. selecting with mouse works too

Comment: Yes, of course. In the DOS box, but not the IDE. Thanks.

Comment: in the IDE, in the console pane

Comment: Whaaat? It works now. Why not before? Anyway, I'm letting the post stand because it's can still be useful to separate the stdout and stderr.

Answer (score 0):

The post [Capturing avrdude command in IDE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/31110/capturing-avrdude-command-in-ide) gave me the clue. Under Windows the file

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino_debug.exe`

can have its output redirected to files same as a shell command.

In the CMD.exe DOS box, I executed:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino>arduino_debug.exe >\temp\logfile.txt 2>\temp\errfile.txt`

and the regular log stuff went to logfile and the errors and warnings went to errfile.

There's enough material in those two files to hurt yourself.